# pmml in R generating improper variable names

Tags: r, pmml

I am using the pmml package in R to generate PMML for Logistic Regression model obtained using the glm function as follows:

```
library(pmml)
var <- sample(c(1,2,3),100,replace = TRUE)
var_cat <- sample(c(1,2,3,4),100,replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(y = as.factor(y),var = as.factor(var), var_cat = as.factor(var_cat))
model <- glm(y ~ ., data = df, family = binomial)
pmmlOutput <- pmml(model)
```

The PPMatrix portion of this PMML is shown below:

```
<PPMatrix>
   <PPCell value="2" predictorName="var" parameterName="p1"/>
   <PPCell value="3" predictorName="var" parameterName="p2"/>
   <PPCell value="_cat2" predictorName="var" parameterName="p3"/>
   <PPCell value="2" predictorName="var_cat" parameterName="p3"/>
   <PPCell value="_cat3" predictorName="var" parameterName="p4"/>
   <PPCell value="3" predictorName="var_cat" parameterName="p4"/>
   <PPCell value="_cat4" predictorName="var" parameterName="p5"/>
   <PPCell value="4" predictorName="var_cat" parameterName="p5"/>
</PPMatrix>
```

The first variable and its levels appear alright as (var,2) and (var,3). However, there are two lines for the second variable with the variable name and the levels getting split at the wrong location.

Instead of getting (var_cat,2), it is getting split into (var,_cat2) as highlighted below:

```
<PPCell value="_cat2" predictorName="var" parameterName="p3"/>
```

This seems to happen only when there are overlapping variable names (in this case var and var_cat). However, this works fine if only var_cat variable is present.

Could someone suggest a way to address this issue?

Comment: I get the same thing, pmml version 1.4.2.  Looks like a bug.  I guess just avoid overlapping variable names.  `packageDescription("pmml")` gives you a support address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct; you have found a bug in the R code.

The way it finds the values effectively assumes that different variable
names are not substrings of another.

Since `var` is a `substring` of `var_cat`, you get this error. Notice that `var_cat` and `cat` would also potentially give you the same problem. On the other hand, `var_cat1` is *not* a `substring` of `var_cat2`, so that should work.

For now, the easiest way is to just name the variables so that a 
variable name is not a substring of another. Fortunately we are planning 
a new release in the next couple of weeks, I will try to include a fix 
for this in that release.